# How can I use Material UI React Grid (which utilizes CSS Flexbox) to have my items wrap, evenly spaced, but in a specific grid

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, grid, material-ui

In my React application I am using Material UI React. I'm trying to utilize the `<Grid>` component so that I can have 10 items in a flexbox.

I'm not sure what combination to properly use to get my items spaced out evenly in a perfect grid. When the items are a perfect grid (i.e. 10 items, 2 rows of 5), it works nicely. But as I change the screen size to account for responsive design, the rows are not perfect. The closest I can get is shown in the image, but I still want all of the items evenly spaced (not all that blank space to the right side).

---

[image: Too much space to the right side]

---

Another attempt, which is definitely not what I want because of the last row:

[image: Even spacing is not perfect]

Comment: I think you can use breakpoints of material ui [https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#grid-with-breakpoints](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#grid-with-breakpoints)

Comment: Can you please add the code or try this <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center" justify="space-evenly">

Answer (score 0):

try the `justify={'space-between'}` or `justify={'space-around'}` as a prop of the parent grid